# Accelerometer data from hex to float

Tags: swift, floating-point, hex, decimal

I am trying to get accelerometer data off a *poorly* documented BLE beacon. Here is what I receive (as NSDictionary):

```
{
    "x-Data" = 0020;
    "y-Data" = 0000;
    "z-Data" = 0BEC;
}
```

and... I cannot figure out what it should mean. The accelerometer has a scale setting. The scale setting in this case is `+-2g`. I therefore expect the values that I receive above should be in `[-1,1]`, and I multiply be the scale to get an actual measurement value.

I took data with the accelerometer sitting flat on a table; I expect that the values then should be `x=0,y=0` and `z=-0.5` - because multiplying by the scale (`2g`) gives `z=-1g` = gravity.

The data I receive is 2 bytes. Is it a half-float format (Float16)? But trying to convert this is no good:

```
let u = UInt16("0BEC", radix: 16)! // 3052
Float16(bitPattern: u) // 0.0002418
```

Did I convert it wrong?

I've been going through guesses for a little while now for the format. Can you help me figure out what is the format?

Here is a slightly bigger set of values with the accelerometer sitting on a table:

```
{
    "x-Data" = 001C;
    "y-Data" = 0FFC;
    "z-Data" = 0BEC;
}
{
    "x-Data" = 0020;
    "y-Data" = 0FFC;
    "z-Data" = 0BE8;
}
{
    "x-Data" = 001C;
    "y-Data" = 0000;
    "z-Data" = 0BE8;
}
{
    "x-Data" = 001C;
    "y-Data" = 0FFC;
    "z-Data" = 0BEC;
}
{
    "x-Data" = 0020;
    "y-Data" = 0000;
    "z-Data" = 0BEC;
}
```

Comment: Looks like 12bit fixpoint

Comment: I think you're right, although before you mention it I've never heard of such a thing. Float12

Comment: Not float12, just 12bit integers ranging from `'0x800' == -0x800 == -2g` to `0x7ff == +2g`

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it for hours and finally writing this question, I found the answer to my own question, although I'd still like an explanation.

I found that if I move the last digit (always 0) to the front, I get the right answer:

```
let acc = UInt16("BEC0", radix: 16)! // Use BEC0 instead of 0BEC
let accs = Int16(bitPattern: acc)
Double(accs) / Double(32767) // - 0.5 as desired
```

I'm really not sure why the accelerometer data is in this format. I get it just converting the raw data to an NSDictionary. Possibly it's bug in the firmware on the beacon.